# pictureBox image change by clicking a button in win form app

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm creating a little game with windows form app. in this game the user have 5 tries.
so I want to show remaining tries in a picture box.
for example:
at the beginning the picture box image is show num5 icon.
when the user click the button the picture box show num4 icon and so on. 
what can I do?

Comment: create a class level variable that holds the current number. Increment on each click. Put the images or the imagenames in a List<T>. Assign the next one on each click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call this method each click :

```
 // it's global var refers to image
 int count = 1;

 // use count to load the next image
 void loadNextPic()
 {
     string picPath = "../Pics/imageNum" + count.ToString() + ".jpg";
     pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(picPath);
     count++;
 }
```

Remember you need to name the images as "imageNum1.jpg", "imageNum2.jpg" and so on.